# "He would do that, would he?" Is this correct?

Tags: word-choice

I've always known a type of sentences like this:

> He would do that, **wouldn't** he?

However, what about

> "He would do that, **would** he?"

Is this correct?

Maybe I'm wrong, the first one expresses a different thought?

Comment: In *"He would do that, **wouldn't he**?"*, the last two words are a standard "question tag" - the whole utterance carries the sense *I think he would do that, and I [rhetorically] invite you to agree with me"*. It's "rhetorical" because the speaker doesn't necessarily expect a reply (though if there *is* a reply, it's expected to be affirmative). But *"He would do that, **would he**?"* expresses surprise/disbelief that he would do such a thing - it's a genuine question, with the sense *Would he **really** do that?*.

Comment: The normal tag question swaps negation values; but this is not that construction. This is a diffrent one, and it's got a definite attitude problem. Everything depends on the intonation. It can also be a threat, or an accusation of fecklessness, or a lot of other things besides a genuine information question.

Comment: FumbleFingers and John Lawler: You are answering this question. Why not put your remarks in the answer spaces?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I recently saw the " would he " form in a movie ( don't remember which one but Evil under the sun is a possibility) and the expression seemed like just as you say. And yes I do agree about intonation "would he?" part is rather said surprised

Comment: "He would do that. Or would he?" (second thoughts/ 'but then again') is probably what's implied.

Comment: @FumbleFingers As regards the use of *he would wouldn't he* one cannot pass without reference to the most famous instance of the use of the expression in 1963 by [Mandy Rice-Davies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandy_Rice-Davies).

Comment: @WS2: I was just about to nitpick by pointing out that what she actually said was *Well he would **say** that, wouldn't he?* But having checked your link (which specifically points out that it's "often misquoted" with the extra word which she never said) I just feel like a bit of a nit myself now! Still, I'm now ready to pick nits more accurately next time I hear someone else misquote the line as I *would* have done before you led me to enlightenment. (So if people start accusing me of being a fastidious pedant, I'll blame you! :)

Answer (score 1):

The first example is very common and can have slightly different meanings depending on which word is emphasized:

> *He* would do that, wouldn't he? — Wouldn't he be the one that does that instead of me?
>
> He *would* do that, wouldn't he? — Yeah, of course he did that. I should have seen that coming.
>
> He would do *that*, wouldn't he? — He would probably do that, given the circumstances.
>
> He would do that, *wouldn't* he? — I think he would do that. Do you agree?
>
> He would do that, wouldn't he? — I think he would do that; I assume you agree.

The other sentence is less common and really only has two interpretations:

> He would do that, would he? — I think he would do that. Do you agree?
>
> He would do *that*, would he? — I don't think he would do that. Why do you think he would?

The second emphasis is very much like the sentence, "Oh you think so, do you?"

---

By the way, another variation of this sentence is:

> He wouldn't do that, would he?

This typically means "I don't think he would do that. Do you agree?" but emphasis can shift the meaning around as much as the first example detailed above.